# Matlab matrix accessing columns

Tags: matlab

Can someone explain what is happening here? 
I know that Y(:,1) is the first column of values in Y.
But what does Y(p,1) mean?
**Matlab noob**

```
Y = load('testFile.txt');  %Load file
p = randperm(length(Y));   %List of random numbers between 0 and Y size

Y(:,1) = Y(p,1);
Y(:,2) = Y(p,2);
Y(:,3) = Y(p,4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Y = load('testFile.txt');  %Load file
% create a mapping to shuffle the rows of Y.
% This assumes more rows than columns in Y, otherwise the code doesn't make sense.
% This is because length(Y) returns the length of the largest dimension.
% A more robust implementation would use size(Y,1) rather than length(Y).
p = randperm(length(Y));   %List of random numbers between 0 and Y size

% Rearrange the rows of column 1 based on the shuffled order
Y(:,1) = Y(p,1);
% Rearrange the rows of column 2 based on the shuffled order
Y(:,2) = Y(p,2);
% Set the third column to the shuffled fourth column.
Y(:,3) = Y(p,4);
```